# Using DirectorySearcher to retrieve certain properties doesn't return a value

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm currently trying to write a function that allows me to get a number of additional attributes for an Active Directory user. To get those attributes I'm using `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` and it does work for some attributes like `postalCode` or `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` but not for others like `profilePath` and I'm puzzled why.

I'm using code that looks similar to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ADReaderTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "doe";
            string additionalAttributes = "postalCode,profilePath";
            DirectoryEntry adConnection = 
              new DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=contoso,DC=local", "CONTOSO\\User", "Password");
            DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(adConnection);
            adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SamAccountName");
            adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSID");

            foreach(string attribute in additionalAttributes.Split(',')){
                adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attribute);
            }

            adSearch.Filter = "(&(|((&objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))(objectCategory=group))(cn=*" + name + "*))";

            SearchResultCollection adSearchResult = adSearch.FindAll();

            Console.WriteLine("There were " + adSearchResult.Count + " matches for *" + name + "*");
            foreach(SearchResult user in adSearchResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Listing Properties for " + user.Path);
                foreach (string prop in user.Properties.PropertyNames) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Prop: " + prop);
                    for(int i = 0; i < user.Properties[prop].Count; i++){
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + user.Properties[prop][i].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If I debug that code I can see that `postalCode` and `profilePath` are both added to the list of properties that should be loaded but in the result `user` only has `postalCode` from the `additionalAttributes` string. Even if I add `*` to the properties that should be loaded `profilePath` is missing. So what could I try to do to find out why attributes are missing?

Other things I've tried:

- Check whenever the attributes are visible (they are) using the credentials using:

  - AD user and computer MMC
  - [LDP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx#DoingASearchUsingLDP)
- Compare the number of properties returned by `Get-ADUser <user> -Properties *` with the number of properties returned this way. The result is that the cmdlet returns way more attributes (~2 times as many). As some of those are certainly computed (e.g. `AccountExpirationDate` and `AccoutnExpires`) I'm not sure if it's a good indicator.
- Verify that the properties actually have a value assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else is running into the same problem you should make sure your path/connection string is the right one. In this case (as indicated by the `GC://`) I'm binding to the global catalog and the global catalog [doesn't contain all attributes](http://www.selfadsi.org/global-catalog-attributes.htm). If you actually want to query LDAP use the [`LDAP://` provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.path(v=vs.110).aspx)...